# Rest API: The Requested Resource does not Exist

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to get a Salesforce REST API Integeration to work and struggling quite a bit.

I've got a successful authentication via OAuth that returns an access_token.

I'm using that access token as "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" header when trying to make further requests. However, whatever my request looks like, I get

```
[
  {
    "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
  }
]
```

as response.

**Details:**

I request the header via CURL:

```
curl  -XPOST  "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token" \
  --data-urlencode "grant_type=password" \
  --data-urlencode "username=$EMAIL" \
  --data-urlencode "password=$PASSWORD$SECURITY_TOKEN" \
  --data-urlencode "client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET" \
  --data-urlencode "client_id=$CLIENT_ID"
```

the response i am getting looks like this:

```
{
  "access_token": "TOKEN_VALUE",
  "instance_url": "https://xxx.my.salesforce.com",
  "id": "https://test.salesforce.com/id/xxx/xxx",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "issued_at": "1558087410145",
  "signature": "xxx"
}
```

Then, using that access token to craft a request (same result for any request - tried many different ones):

```
curl "https://xxx.my.salesforce.com/services/data/45.0/sobjects/Lead/listviews"  \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_VALUE'
```

Response

```
[
  {
    "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
  }
]
```

The Connected App has "full" permission, and the username/password credentials i log in with has access to the data I am querying via 
lightning web. I also verified that API Version 45 corresponds to the salesforce version used.

Du you have any suggestions, on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a typo in your rest resource

its not

```
/services/data/45.0/sobjects/Lead/listviews
```

its v45.0

```
/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Lead/listviews
```

Comment: thanks a lot! After all the hassle to find out about permissions, IP whitelisting,... such a simple mistake ;)

Comment: @Matthias - no worries happens :)